# How can I fill holes in a plastic shower surround and make them disappear?

Tags: plastic

I put the 2 inch holes for the faucet in the wrong spot. How do I make it look like there was never holes there in a plastic shower surround?

Comment: Quite hard to make it disappear, can maybe limit the difference.   Will probably need to glue a piece of the same plastic to seal it.  Would suggest rather than trying to make it disappear, to glue other circles(different colours/shapes) on it and make a simple design.  Hide it in plain sight

Comment: You might instead ask how to use the holes you have. Ecnerwal is right--you can't undo this.

Comment: Slim chance, but can you move the plumbing to suit your holes?

Answer (score 1):

You go buy another one, and chalk it up to learning the "measure twice (or more,) cut once" rule.

Or you repair it in a visible manner and the lesson remains the same.